# How to extract bearer token from curl json response and pass it as authorization header a different api call?

Tags: json, bash, api, curl, microservices

I am making a call to OAuth API using curl command by passing username,password and getting the bearer token response as JSON  which is in the below format.

```
curl -X POST https://api.mysite.com/oauth/token -u "login:password"
```

Response

```
{
   "token_type:"Bearer",
   "access_token:" "cfdadfa3234sfsdfxx......",
   "issued_at":15234234234,
   "expires_in":953343434,
   "scope": "asdfasd234234234asfasdfasdfaflalsdfkasjfa;sdfassdflj"
}
```

I need to get only the access_token value which is the bearer token from this curl JSON response and I need to pass as Authorization header  to a different  apigee gateway hosted api call.

```
curl -X GET https://apigee.mysite.com/getorderstatus -H "Authroization Bearer ???need to pass bearer token here ???"
```

How do I parse the JSON and get the bearer token as variable and pass it to the next API call?

I need to do this on the windows server. My environment is only limited to Windows. I can't install packages like jq due to security reason.

Answer (score 0):

The recommended way to extract something from JSON is `jq`.

However, if you're really sure that the output is always like this, you might

```
at=$(curl -X POST https://api.mysite.com/oauth/token -u "login:password" | sed -n 's/[ ,"]//g;s/"access_token://p')
curl -X GET https://apigee.mysite.com/getorderstatus -H "$at"
```

A bash-only solution would be:

```
curl -X POST https://api.mysite.com/oauth/token -u "login:password" | 
while read line ; do
    if [[ "$line" == *access_token* ]] ; then
        at=${line%\"*}
        at=${at##*\"}
        curl -X GET https://apigee.mysite.com/getorderstatus -H "$at"
    fi
done
```

Note that, due to the subshell, `at` is not available outside the loop.

Comment: Sed is not working for me since i am on windows environment.

Comment: That is a very limited environment!. Added a bash-only solution.

Comment: @LjmDullaart They should have a LOL option for comments.  Yours made me laugh.  Out loud too.